# The way we should utilise the contentView of getView method in BaseAdapter

Tags: android

Implemented a custom ListView with the help of a custom Adapter (CheckBox and TextView). I understand that the contentView is used someway when the ListView items get recycled {say items deleted or not in display etc.,}. But yet my understanding of this contentView is vague.

Can someone explain me the way we should utilise this contentView argument of BaseAdapter.getView() and what happens when an item in the listView gets deleted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a normal listview you'll notice that all entries look identical *(=have the same layout)*. Also keep in mind that building a layout from XML is expensive *(inflating)*.

What the `ListView` does here is pretty simple. When you scroll down the list, one entry gets hidden at the top and a new one gets shown on the bottom. To prevent a expensive XML inflation for the newly visible entry at this point, you'll get supplied with the layout from the entry that just got hidden. It got all it's old data in there, but you don't have to build it from scratch, which is better when it comes to efficiency. Just fill it with the new data. And that's the whole idea.

Just check if the `contentView` is not `null` *(in this case android has an old view for you)*, in this case just add the data for the new entry. If it's null, inflate the layout from scratch.